# Odoo13: how can I relate to Many2many field in another model?

Tags: python, python-3.x, many-to-many, odoo, odoo-13

I have a field: Many2many in one model and I want to use it in another model. What is the good practice of referring to Many2Many field?

Answer (score 3):

```
many2many_field_name = fields.Many2many(related='partner_id.many2many_field_name')
```

Add this field definition to `crm.lead` model, and of course replace `many2many_field_name` with your desired field name in you `res.partner` model in `related` parameter.